# Classifying a set of photos to places

Tags: classification, clustering, spatial, k-means, k-nearest-neighbour

I want to cluster photos and map them to places.

As input I have

- Photos with locations (lat, long)
- Places - some as (imprecise) bounding boxes, some just as points, maybe others as bounding geometries

However, all are not exact - photos relating to a building will be taken near, but outside the building.

Also, bounding boxes are overlapping (e.g., a photo of Golden Gate Bridge may be outside the bounding box of Golden Gate Bridge and inside California, but should be labeled as Golden Gate Bridge).

There are also tags which can serve as additional input - similarity in tags which are not 'generic' but 'local' could serve as another distance metric between photos, I think. But many photos are not tagged well, so this doesn't help much.

I'm now using K-means / K-means-plus-plus and getting photo clusters, and now plan to somehow match their bounding box to place bounding boxes and assign them this way (probably by finding the bounding box which has the biggest intersection with photo cluster bounding box).

Another option seems to be KNN, but I'm not sure how to best adjust the algorithm for the fact that the places are mostly as bounding boxes, and overlapping. Maybe generate synthetic points for each of the place bounding boxes, then apply KNN?

Questions:

- Am I missing some proven algorithms to do this?
- What is the best way to map clusters of points to bounding boxes?
- How to best adapt KNN for the fact that the 'training set' are actually bounding boxes, and that they overlap?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think clustering is the way to go here.

You have labeled data (your bounding boxes), so it's probably best to use them.

You can compute point-to-rectangle distances, too. So maybe kNN is the way to go!
Or use e.g. point to center divided by size of the bounding box.